# Outlook ignorelist?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, auto-reply

i searched a lot, but is there some kind of ignorelist in outlook?
maybe with special "away-messages" ?

would be very useful i think ..

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Answer (score 1):

From Microsoft Word help:

> Add a name to the Blocked Senders List
>
> 1. On the Tools menu, click Options.
> 2. On the Preferences tab, under
>      E-mail, click Junk E-mail.
> 3. Click the Blocked Senders tab.
> 4. Click Add.
> 5. In the Enter an e-mail address or
>      Internet domain name to be added to
>      the list box, enter the name or
>      address you want added, and then
>      click OK.
> 6. Repeat steps 4 and 5 for
>      each name or address that you want
>      to add.
>
> Notes
>
> You can quickly add a name to the Blocked Senders List by right-clicking the junk e-mail message, and then, on the shortcut menu, pointing to Junk E-mail and clicking Add Sender to Blocked Senders List on the shortcut menu.

Answer (score 1):

By using the rules feature in Outlook, you can automatically dispose of messages in various ways, such as move them to folders, or to the trash, or send a reply. I guess you want to identify the ignored messages by sender, and rules can do this, or you can use other criteria, such as subject, etc.